# Symfony 3 / Apache - Post request gives Error 500

Tags: apache, symfony

I have a Symfony 3 API and I'm trying to register a user but I have an error 500 when executing a POST request (GET request works). It's probably a problem with my Apache configuration because I don't have any errors in my logs files. A `var_dump('ok')` at the top of my function also give me error 500.

**My Apache configuration:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subscription.api.local
    ServerAlias www.subscription.api.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/subscription_backend/web
    DirectoryIndex /app.php

    <Directory /var/www/subscription_backend/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        FallbackResource /app.php
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/subscription_backend>
        Options FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/subscription_backend/web/bundles>
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/subscription-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/subscription-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Line added in my hosts file:**

```
127.0.0.1 subscription.api.local www.subscription.api.local
```

My projet is in `~/Projects/subscription_backend` directory and I use a symbolic to `/var/www/subscription_backend` :

```
sudo ln -s  ~/Projects/subscription_backend /var/www/subscription_backend
```

**Permissions of "~/Projects/subscription_backend directory":**
[image]

**Permissions of "/var/www/subscription_backend directory":**
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 55 avril 19 21:45 /var/www/subscription_backend -> /home/khan/Projects/subscription_backend/`

What's wrong with my configuration ? Why GET request works but not POST ?

Thx

Comment: Did you check server logs and Symfony's logs?

Comment: No, I don't have any logs error

Comment: Could you set your Symfony app on your server in "debug" mode to see the errors?

Comment: My error is ```Session Storage was not able to create directory
"Projects/subscription_backend/var/sessions/prod"``` I tried ```sudo chmod -R 777 var/*``` but not working. And also, I don't have sessions directory under var/

Comment: After adding manually the sessions directory ```mkdir -p var/sessions && sudo chmod 777 -R var/sessions```. Now, I have the following error ```"Attempted to load class "Memcached" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?"```

Comment: Great one bug fixed! Now for the other one, did you install the memcache extension? did you require any memache library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i solved the problem.

First,fix permissions https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup/file_permissions.html:

```
cd ~/Projects/subscription_backend

rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/logs/*
HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data [n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)

sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
composer install
```

Then install memcache extension:

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
sudo apt-get install php-memcached
sudo apt-get install php-memcache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Clear cache:

```
bin/console c:c
bin/console c:c --env=prod
```